# Parse PHP Sdk - Can't fetch results by date

Tags: php, parse-platform

I have a class named `orders` and I want to see all the orders that were made this week; for that, I have the following:

```
        $sevenDaysAgo = date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u', strtotime('-7 days'));

        $query = new ParseQuery("orders");
        $query->greaterThanOrEqualTo("createdAt", $sevenDaysAgo);
        $count = $query->count();
        // The count request succeeded. Show the count
        echo "Only " . $count . " Results.";
```

Knowing that I've already Data that can be shown, with the above code, I am getting `0` results.

Do I have something wrong?